# Parse free text into dict with Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert this *kind* free text into a dictionary with Regex.

> alamine A (12 000 UI/kg), thiamine D3 (1 200 UI/kg), niacine E (70 mg/kg), zinc [sous forme d'oxyde de zinc] (70 mg/kg), zinc [sous forme de chélate de zinc d'acides aminés, hydraté] (45 mg/kg), copper [sous forme de sulfate de cuivre (II), pentahydraté] (10 mg/kg), iode [sous forme d'iodate de calcium, anhydre] (2 mg/kg),  sélénium [sous forme de sélénite de sodium] (0.2 mg/kg), cyaobactin12 (0.2%)

Idea is to capture  key and value

- **key** : alamine A
- **value** : 12 000 UI/kg

or

- **key** : copper [sous forme de sulfate de cuivre (II), pentahydraté]
- **value** : 10 mg/kg

I tried to options to achieve this text conversion :

**First approach** : directly with regex `(()\((\d*\.*\s*\d*\s*)(UI\/kg|mg\/kg|%)\))`but I'm only able to isolate properly value and not key.

**Second approach :**

1. Get rid of '**,**' inside brackets with this kind of regex `(\[.*),(.*\]`which doesn't capture exactly [sous forme de sulfate de cuivre (II)**,** pentahydraté] or [sous forme d'iodate de calcium**,** anhydre]

   2. Split along "," to have list looking like list ["alamine A (12 000 UI/kg)","thiamine D3 (1200 UI/kg)" ...] 
      3 . For each element of the list, use an easier regex as first approach `(.*)\((\d*\.*\s*\d*\s*)(UI\/kg|mg\/kg|%)\))`

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the simpler piece: the value.
It's something enclosed in parentheses: `(?P<value>\([^)]+\))`

```
(?P<value> # Capturing "value" group
  \(       # Matches an opening parentheses
  [^)]+    # Matches one or more non ")" characters
  \)       # Matches a closing parentheses
)
```

This done, let's deal with the key.
One point here, the key may include some text enclosed in square brackets.
Then it's any non `(` or `[` characters, and may be followed by anything enclosed in brackets: `(?P<key>[^[(]+(?:\[[^]]+\])?)`

```
(?P<key>  # Capturing "key" group
  [^[(]+  # One or more non "(" or "[" characters
  (?:     # Non-capturing group
    \[    # An opening bracket
    [^]]+ # One or more non "]" characters
    \]    # A closing bracket
  )?      # Non-capturing group made optional
)
```

Job is almost complete.
We will add a `\s` between both our groups as separator between them.
And to finish, let's deal with the series separator: `(?:(?<=,\s)|^)`

```
(?:        # Non-capturing group
  (?<=,\s) # Either preceded by a coma and a space
  |^       # Or alternatively beginning the string
)
```

Now put it all together: [`(?:(?<=,\s)|^)(?P<key>[^[(]+(?:\[[^]]+\])?)\s(?P<value>\([^)]+\))`](https://regex101.com/r/bOjXMo/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
(?:^|,)(.*?)(\((?:\d*\.*\s*\d*\s*)(?:UI\/kg|mg\/kg|%)\))
```

When you break it down, you will see that each 'section' of your keys and values must start with either the start of string or the comma from the last section with the non-capturing group `(?:^|,)`.

Then it will capture everything up to the next opening parenthesis using a non-greedy quantifier `(.*?)\(`. This is your 'Key'.

Finally it will capture your value with your existing code, modified slightly:

```
(\((?:\d*\.*\s*\d*\s*)(?:UI\/kg|mg\/kg|%)\))
```

If you want to trim the excess spaces from the capture, you can add `\s*` to either side of the key group:

```
(?:^|,)\s*(.*?)\s*(\((?:\d*\.*\s*\d*\s*)(?:UI\/kg|mg\/kg|%)\))
```

### [See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/mKpPpQ/2)

Answer (score 1):

There you go my friend! I use a regex to found every single result, then I split them on the last `(`. It is covering every of your exception in your string!!!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
text = "alamine A (12 000 UI/kg), thiamine D3 (1 200 UI/kg), niacine E (70 mg/kg), zinc [sous forme d'oxyde de zinc] (70 mg/kg), zinc [sous forme de chélate de zinc d'acides aminés, hydraté] (45 mg/kg), copper [sous forme de sulfate de cuivre (II), pentahydraté] (10 mg/kg), iode [sous forme d'iodate de calcium, anhydre] (2 mg/kg), sélénium [sous forme de sélénite de sodium] (0.2 mg/kg), cyaobactin12 (0.2%)"
my_regex = re.compile(r"([^,]*\[[^\]]*\]\s\([^\)]*\)|[^,]*\([^\)]*\))")
matches = re.findall(my_regex, text)
clean_result = []
for str in matches:
    res = str.rsplit('(', 1)
    clean_result.append((res[0].strip(), res[1][:-1]))

for res in clean_result:
    print "key : " + res[0].decode('utf-8')
    print "value : " + res[1].decode('utf-8')
    print
```

Output

```
key : alamine A
value : 12 000 UI/kg

key : thiamine D3
value : 1 200 UI/kg

key : niacine E
value : 70 mg/kg

key : zinc [sous forme d'oxyde de zinc]
value : 70 mg/kg

key : zinc [sous forme de chélate de zinc d'acides aminés, hydraté]
value : 45 mg/kg

key : copper [sous forme de sulfate de cuivre (II), pentahydraté]
value : 10 mg/kg

key : iode [sous forme d'iodate de calcium, anhydre]
value : 2 mg/kg

key : sélénium [sous forme de sélénite de sodium]
value : 0.2 mg/kg

key : cyaobactin12
value : 0.2%
```